# Hyperledger Fabric Read User Attribute for v1.0

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In v0.6 i am able to read the user attribute using the shim.ChaincodeStubInterface.ReadCertAttribute.

However in v1.0 i am not able to buld the code as it will return a compilation error:

stub.ReadCertAttribute undefined (type shim.ChaincodeStubInterface has no field or method ReadCertAttribute).

I cant seem to to find out what is the equivalent function for v1.0.

May i know how can i read the user attribute for v1.0?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent function does not exist for v1.0 (see [FAB-2046](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-2046)).

In Fabric v1.0, access control can be accomplished via [policies](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/policies.html) that are [configured on channels](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configtx.html). There are also [endorsement policies](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endorsement-policies.html) that help peers determine if a transaction has been properly endorsed.

Fabric v1.0 also includes new methods on the chaincode stub API that you can use to perform your own ACL, including possibly replicating the functionality of `ReadCertAttribute`:

- [`GetSignedProposal()`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L182-L184) – returns the transaction proposal currently being executed.
- [`GetCreator()`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L166-L169) – handy method to just get the identity of the submitter of the transaction.
- [`GetTransient()`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L171-L177) – returns transient data attached to the transaction proposal